# OS hanging on reboot after update

Tags: boot

I am unable to reboot successfully after recent updates that first took me from 5.4.0-48 to 5.40-54, then after ran a repair from the Grub menu, I was upgraded to 5.4.0-65. Neither of the last two boots successfully. I am currently able to fully boot if I choose 5.4.0-48. I checked repositories but am not seeing anything unique except a few "ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED" bionic repos. Although I have an AMD graphics controller, I do not recall installing any specific drivers.

I do recall that the last set of updates did not install and the OS kept getting stuck. I had also tried to install two free word processing apps from App Center which kept hanging as well.

Can someone help me figure out what could be going on? Thanks in advance for any suggestons!

Srini

Comment: I think I'd try recovery mode, dropping to a prompt, and then running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`. If that fails, it will probably give you some instructions such as running `sudo apt-get -f install` and/or `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: Thanks, that did move things along. I am using the cryptsetup package and there are other packages that have dependencies on this one. I had to use `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite` with the full path to the .deb file to get things moving along. I have successfully upgrade but now have further problems trying to install further available updates. I keep seeing a "loading cache" message in AppCenter and then no further activity. However, thank you very much for helping things move along. Much appreciated. Will update later if I can figure out what this cache issue is.

Comment: You can ask a new question about the new errors.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @KGIII helped me move along in the right direction. I am thankful for the help. It seems that the hanging problem was due to the "cryptsetup" package failing on dependencies. Very strange that AppCenter and its associated processes did not have permissions to overwrite files. I was required to use the "--force-overwrite" option and used "dpkg" to manually fix the issue. Of course, all of this was done by dropping to the command prompt to be able to view the messages. Perhaps they were also written to a log but I did not check.